# Sudoers file messed up

Tags: files, sudo, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I accidentally made a mistake in the `sudoers` file, and now I can't fix it because if I try to change the file it give a permission denied message. If I use `sudo` to open the file, then it says syntax error and no valid `sudoers` sources found and won't execute the command. I'm on raspbian, a flavor of debian.

Does anyone know how to get out of this catch-22?

Comment: USE visudo that's what it's for. NEVER edit sudoers directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to have to boot into single user mode.

https://serverfault.com/questions/482079/debian-boot-to-single-user-mode

As the root user, you'll be able to edit the sudoers file to fix it.  I highly recommend using the `visudo` command to edit your sudoers file in the future, to prevent having to go through this again, as visudo does a syntax check on the file before saving it.

Comment: Thanks for the `visudo` advice, but I don't know how to boot into single user mode.  The only pre-boot option I have takes me to a graphical window where I can only edit `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt`

Answer (score 8):

1. If you know the `root` password (and it is set) you can use `su` to became `root` and edit `/etc/sudoers`.
2. If your root filesystem is on SD-card, you can push it out and edit `/etc/sudoers` on PC or any other device, provided it have card reader.
3. You can enter U-Boot (bootloader) command line (usually by pressing a button on keyboard or via the UART) and add `1` to Linux kernel command line to enter single user mode. In this mode you will be `root` and could edit `/etc/sudoers`. See also [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/oops-i-need-runlevel-1).

Comment: I haven't set a root password yet, but I will try the other options.

Comment: It seems `cmdline.txt` is what you need. Add literal `1` at the end and you will go to single user mode. _Do not forget to delete it after_.

Comment: Yes it worked!1

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a cloud instance you are in a bit more trouble.

There are techniques depending on distro, but if you have Docker already installed and running, then you can generally go through a Docker container to fix the problem. That is because, usually, the Docker service is running as root and anything done to a mounted volume inside the container is affected as root on the host.

On host:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v /etc:/usr/local/etc busybox sh
```

The "busybox" is just a nice small distro that won't take long to download. If you already have a Docker image that has a shell available in it, just use that.

On Docker Container:

```
cd /usr/local/etc
vi sudoers
```

You may have added a bad file to the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory. In which case, probably just remove that file.

When you exit the container, you can `sudo` again.

Whew!

Comment: worked like a charm, nice trick